# xsl extensionFunctions returning fo string

Tags: java, xml, xslt, apache-fop

How could i achive something like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:test="java:Hello">
  <xsl:template match="/">
     <test:Hola getTransformationOf="."/>
  </xsl:template>
```

and my class Hello have a methode Hola returning a formated stream like

```
<fo:block>.......< /fo:block>
```

If i use `<xsl:value-of select="test:MyMethode(.)"/>`
    the stream `<fo:block>.......</fo:block>` will be presented as a string not as an FO instruction

PS: the transformation should be in a java class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to use xsl:copy-of ... as in:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="test:MyMethode(.)"/>
```

or possibly your "string" result is being escaped, so try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="test:myMethode(.)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

I have used both methods to return inline SVG into XSL FO to be interpreted as nodes and not a string. I think it really depends on what MyMethode() is returning as a data type.

Comment: MyMethode return a formated stream like:<fo:block>.......< /fo:block>
The right answer is : <xsl:value-of select="test:myMethode(.)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>